# Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.proxy.ProxyApi$ProxyResult

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

When I build my android application, I saw this error:

```
 Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.proxy.ProxyApi$ProxyResult
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post both app level and project level `build.gradle` file here

Comment: Please add the content of your both gradle files and please also responde with @AlexMamo